# Shopware 6 B2B suite - override typescript plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, shopware6, b2b

In shopware 6 there is this B2B plugin that delivers javascript functionality to the storefront in form of typescript plugin files. These typescript plugins are extremely similar to the regular js plugins in storefront.

This is an example of a filename of a ts plugin of the B2B suite: `order-list-new-positions.plugin.ts`.

And this is an example of a typescript plugin class definition:

```
...
interface Endpoints {
    productName: string,
    unitPrice: string,
    create: string,
}

@EventInterface
export default class OrderListNewPositionsPlugin extends window.PluginBaseClass {
    public static options = {
        SELECTOR_ROW: '.new-line-item__row',
        SELECTOR_ROWS: '.new-line-item__rows',
...
```

So, I try to perform an override on some of the functions on these typescript plugins.
The only relevant resource I found on this is [here](https://www.shopware.com/en/news/b2b-the-hybrid-plugin/). In the Javascript section they say typescript plugins can be overriden in two ways:

1. Like in this code snippet [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shopwareGists/ccef642694277d8b74a53fc16dccf9d7/raw/0599ac76990699abbd986d03701f3f9adcfc7db9/ajax-template.js). I tried this and it doesn't work because the plugins just don't exist in the scope of the jquery object. I called the plugins as like `$.orderlistMultiEdit`, `$.orderListMultiEdit`, `$.orderlistMultiEditPlugin`, `$.orderListMultiEditPlugin`. The plugins are just not registered in the jquery object it seems.
2. The second option is to try and override them as the regular storefront plugin classes. `var OrderlistMultiEditPlugin = require("/var/www/html/custom/plugins/SwagB2bPlatform/SwagB2bPlatform/Resources/app/storefront/src/js/plugins/orderlist-multi-edit.plugin.ts");`. Of course this fails and we get syntax errors. Even though (in 2020) they said it will be possible to override these classes as we override shopware storefront js classes. Maybe I can modify the build storefront script to be able to import and process ts files, but it feels wrong.

**Thus, the question is: does anyone know how to override b2b storefront ts plugins ? Did anyone have this problem ? Is there a workaround ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final answer**: it seems this is a known issue, but we don't have much hope of getting a fix anytime soon.

[image]

Comment: It feels like there is still some hope for TypeScript B2B classes override even before they fix it on their end. Please check my answer for more details - I had some luck with that problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem with B2B TypeScript classes override. The problem was that pagination wasn't reset to page number 1 when other filters where updated. User sometimes ended on empty page as he was still on page number for example 5 when results set had only one page. I found that to solve that B2B bug I need to override `handleTriggerEvent` method in `B2B_AutoSubmitPlugin` class. I turned out that overriding B2B is not that simple and I came across your question on stackoverflow ;)

At the end I solved it by injecting a bit of the code into the `PluginManager.register` method. It just detects when B2B registers the plugin with name that I want to alter and on the fly create a class that extents from that plugin.

Here is the working example. Code is in general a bit hacky and probably could be improved but it works fine:

**MyPluginTheme\src\Resources\app\storefront\src\b2b-auto-submit-override.plugin.js**

```js
export const b2bAutoSubmitOverridePlugin = () => {
    const originalRegister = PluginManager.register;

    PluginManager.register = (...args) => {
        if (args[0] === 'B2B_AutoSubmitPlugin') {
            class AutoSubmitOverridePlugin extends args[1] {
                handleTriggerEvent(event) {
                    const eventTarget = event.target;
                    const paginationInput = document.querySelector('.js--b2b-pagination-input');

                    if (paginationInput && !eventTarget.classList.contains('js--b2b-pagination-input')) {
                        paginationInput.value = '1';
                    }

                    super.handleTriggerEvent(event);
                }
            }

            args[1] = AutoSubmitOverridePlugin;
        }

        originalRegister(...args);
    }
}
```

**MyPluginTheme\src\Resources\app\storefront\src\main.js**

```js
import { b2bAutoSubmitOverridePlugin } from './b2b-auto-submit-override.plugin';

b2bAutoSubmitOverridePlugin();
```

You can override any other TypeScript class from B2B suite by following the same pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to override plugins of the B2B suite like any other storefront JS plugin in Shopware 6. Even if they are written in typescript, they'll have to be registered in the plugin manager eventually. [See the documentation here.](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/override-existing-javascript?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to)

With the B2B suites the typescript plugins are registered like this:

```js
// from initB2bPlugins.ts
const { register, initializePlugin } = window.PluginManager;
const plugins = require('../plugins');

const pluginNames = Object.keys(plugins);

pluginNames.forEach((pluginName) => {
    const plugin = plugins[pluginName];
    const { initOnSelector } = plugin.prototype;

    if (!initOnSelector || !selectorHits(initOnSelector)) {
        return;
    }

    const registryPluginName = `B2B_${pluginName}`;
    register(registryPluginName, plugin, initOnSelector);
    initializePlugin(registryPluginName, initOnSelector);
});
```

So you should be able to override that particular plugin like this:

```js
const PluginManager = window.PluginManager;
PluginManager.override('B2B_OrderListNewPositionsPlugin', YourPluginOverride, initOnSelector);
```

Comment: The webpack.config.js defined in the storefront in version 6.14.0.0 seems to overlook the ts files unfortunately. Either I name my entry file index.ts or main.ts, the fileis overlooked unless  change it back to js. I use the same webpack config as defined here: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.16.0/src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/webpack.config.js

Comment: While browsing the storefront open the dev-tools of your browser and in the javascript console execute `window.PluginManager.getPluginList()`. The `B2B_*` plugins should appear in the list and you should be able to override them as described.

Comment: Thanks. I did that before. Unfortunately not all B2B plugins appear in that list :( . They seem to be filtered out by this line:     `if (!initOnSelector || !selectorHits(initOnSelector)) {
        return;
    }`

Comment: You can see in the plugin classes, a few will have an annotation like `@InitOnSelector('.b2b-accordion')`. The plugin will then only be registered when that selector can be found. I wouldn't worry about that though, just check if the plugin is registered `Object.keys(window.PluginManager.getPluginList()).includes('B2B_NameOfPlugin')` and then override depending on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's one problem taken care of. If I manage to override the ts plugins I will mark this answer as helpful and that's it

Comment: How can I check if the ts plugin is initialized ? It seems they a loaded asyncronously. So `Object.keys(window.PluginManager.getPluginList()).includes('B2B_OrderlistMultiEditPlugin')` always returns false because the ts plugin is not initlised yet.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**: when trying to import B2B typescript plugins the storefront build script will always fail because the typescript files of b2b suite have dependencies that are not imported when running npm install in shopware storefront. Thus, when you import a typescript plugin from b2b you will encounter errors like this one: `Can't resolve 'apexcharts' in '/var/www/html/custom/plugins/SwagB2bPlatform/SwagB2bPlatform/Resources/app/storefront/src/js/plugins'`. As of right now I did not find any solution.

Comment: Do you have the tool `jq` installed? (execute `jq --version`)

Comment: Yes, it is `"jquery": "3.5.1"`. The problem is that the shopware build script will not and cannot transpile the b2b typescript files unfortunately. Those files can only be transpiled by the b2b webpack config file, since they have some dependencies which don't exist in the package.json in shopwre storefront.

Comment: I still don't see what you're trying to achieve here. If you want to override the plugin as you claimed in your original post you don't have to import it. You override it when it has been registered in the plugin manager, at which point it has been pre-compiled anyways and it doesn't matter if it was originally written in typescript or not.

Comment: Yes, but my plugin needs to extend (`OverrideOrderlistMultiEditPlugin extends OrderlistMultiEditPlugin`) which is imported from b2b typescript plugin. Then I import my plugin and do the `PluginManager.override...`

Comment: Why would you need to extend the plugin though, when you plan to override the original anyway? Within the override you have access to a super-like callstack using `this.$super` to call the methods or access the props of the overridden plugin. That essentially can make it act like an extension with calls to its parent.

Comment: I mean in order to call `this.$super` a class needs to extend another class. The `PluginManager`'s override deregisters the old plugin and registers a new one. The Override plugin thus needs to extend the original class, in order to be able to call `this.$super`. Maybe I am dumb but I don't see a way out.